# python elasticserch: only exact match can return results

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am new to elasticsearch. There is an item in my index with the title: Using Python with Elasticsearch
When I search for it, I always get zero hit except that I search "Using Python with Elasticsearch" exactly.
like:

**1, The code**

```
    import elasticsearch 
    INDEX_NAME= 'test_1' 
    from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch 
    es = Elasticsearch() 
    es.index(index=INDEX_NAME, doc_type='post', id=1, body={'title': 'Using Python with Elasticsearch', 'tags': ['python', 'elasticsearch', 'tips'], })
    es.indices.refresh(index=INDEX_NAME) 
    res = es.indices.get(index=INDEX_NAME) 
    print res
```

The output is:

```
{u'test_1': {u'warmers': {}, u'settings': {u'index': {u'number_of_replicas': u'1', u'number_of_shards': u'5', u'uuid': u'Z2KLxeQLRay4rFgdK4yo9A', u'version': {u'created': u'2020199'}, u'creation_date': u'1484405704970'}}, u'mappings': {u'post': {u'properties': {u'blog': {u'type': u'string'}, u'title': {u'type': u'string'}, u'tags': {u'type': u'string'}, u'author': {u'type': u'string'}}}}, u'aliases': {}}}
```

**2, I change the mappings with the code below:**

```
INDEX_NAME = 'test_1'
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()
request_body = {
'mappings':{
'post': {
'properties': {
'title': {'type':'text'}
}
}
}
}
if es.indices.exists(INDEX_NAME):
res = es.indices.delete(index = INDEX_NAME)
print(" response: '%s'" % (res))
res = es.indices.create(index = INDEX_NAME, body= request_body, ignore=400)
print res
```

The output is

```
response: '{u'acknowledged': True}'
{u'status': 400, u'error': {u'caused_by': {u'reason': u**'No handler for type [text] declared on field [title]**', u'type': u'mapper_parsing_exception'}, u'root_cause': [{u'reason': u'No handler for type [text] declared on field [title]', u'type': u'mapper_parsing_exception'}], u'type': u'mapper_parsing_exception', u'reason': u'Failed to parse mapping [post]: No handler for type [text] declared on field [title]'}}
```

**3, I update the elasticsearch from 1.9 to (5, 1, 0, 'dev')**

**4, I also try to change the mappings with the code below**

```
request_body = {
'mappings':{
'post': {
'properties': {
**'title': {'type':'string', "index": "not_analyzed"}**
}
}
}
}
```

**5 I also change the mappings in this way**:

```
    request_body = {
'mappings':{
'post': {
'properties': {
**'title': {'type':'string', "index": "analyzed"}**
}
}
}
}
```

but, it still cannot get the hits with the query "Using Python"!
Thanks a lot!!

I only install the python version elasticsearch. The code is only the simple demo code from the web.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: My elasticsearch version is 2.2.1.  So change the mapping from "string" to "text" is not allowed.   But, how can I get the search result with a query not exactly match to the doc stored in es, like "Using Python" .

Answer (score 0):

When you specify `{"index" : "not_analyzed"}` in the mapping, it means that elasticsearch is going to store it as it is without analyzing it. That's why you do not get the result when you search for just "Using Python". With elasticsearch 5.x, if you specify the datatype of your field `type` as `text`, elasticsearch will analyze it first and then store it. With that you will be able to get the match for 'Using Python' in your query. You can find more documentation around the `text` type [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html)

Comment: Thanks! I set the type as text.         However, it outputs this error message:                                              {u'status': 400, u'error': {u'caused_by': {u'reason': u'No handler for type [text] declared on field [title]', u'type': u'mapper_parsing_exception'}.